# Algorithm for "smooth" random numbers

Tags: c#, random

Could anyone give me a hint on how to generate "smooth" random numbers?
Here's what I mean by smooth:

The random numbers shall be used in a game, e.g. for wind direction and strength (does anyone remember goood old "Worms"?). Of course setting random numbers for those values every second or so would look awfully choppy.
I would rather have some kind of smooth oscillation in a given value range. Sort of like a sine wave but much more random.

Does anyone get what I'm after? ;-)
Any ideas on how to achieve this kind of behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: you are probably after a random number to tell you when to change the wind direction if you want to simulate wind. when this random time event occurs change wind direction, but limit the direction to a certain angle and velocity (again random), so simply just pick random numbers within a certain range and build on the change gradually +=1(0.0 - 5.0 randomly) every second (0-3 seconds random again lol) etc. until they reach a random change 0-180 degrees over a certain time which again is random. quite simple, but totally up to you how you implement these times and degree changes etc.

Comment: @Jodrell Benford’s law is totally inapplicable here. The question after the distribution might be an interesting question but Benford’s law simply describes a numerical phenomenon, it doesn’t describe a continuous random number distribution (it does describe a discrete distribution which could be sampled from – but why single out this particular distribution?).

Comment: You could represent wind as a vector and do a moving average with random values. That'll smooth out the fluctuations proportionately with the sample size you average.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, comment deleted. I was just pointing out that random can mean different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the delta (change) to be small, just generate a small random number for the delta.

For example, instead of:

```
windspeed = random (100)                # 0 thru 99 inclusive
```

use something like:

```
windspeed = windspeed - 4 + random (9)  # -4 + 0..8 gives -4..4
if   windspeed > 99: windspeed = 99
elif windspeed <  0: windspeed =  0
```

That way, your wind speed is still kept within the required bounds and it only ever changes gradually.

This will work for absolute values like speed, and also for direction if the thing you're changing gradually is the angle from a fixed direction.

It can pretty well be used for any measurement.

---

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that the windspeed changes with a possibly large delta, but slowly, you can generate your target windspeed as you currently do but move gradually toward it:

```
windspeed = 50
target = windspeed
while true:
    # Only set new target if previous target reached.

    if target == windspeed:
        target = random (100)
    
    # Move gradually toward target.

    if target > windspeed:
        windspeed = windspeed + max (random (4) + 1, target - windspeed)
    else:
        windspeed = windspeed - max (random (4) + 1, target - windspeed)

    sleep (1)
```

Comment: But wouldn't it be possible that the wind speed could get stuck at the upper or lower limit?

Comment: @Boris, yes, what's your point? That's what random weather may do as well :-) If you want to ensure it gravitates toward a specific value (like 50), just weight the random numbers to achieve that.

Comment: Or see my update which disconnects the desired value from the increments.

Answer (score 3):

Perlin (or better simplex) noise would be the first method that comes to mind when generating smoothed noise. It returns a number between 1 and -1, which will add or subtract from the current value. You can multiple that to make it seem less subtle or better yet... make the lowest wind value -1 and highest wind value 1.

Then simply have a seeder as a counter (1,2,3... etc) as the perlin/simplex input keep the values 'smooth'.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new version of a smooth random number. The idea is that our random number is going to be within limits = [average - oscillation, average + oscillation], and will change everytime [-varianciance, +variance].

But, if it reaches the limits, our variance is going to be reduce.

E.g. numbers from [0, 100], with variance of 10. If the current value = 8, then the variance will be [0, 18]

python code:

```
def calculate_smooth_random(current_value, average, oscillation, variance):
    max_value = average + oscillation
    min_value = average - oscillation

    max_limit = min(max_value, current_value + variance)
    min_limit = max(min_value, current_value - variance)
    total_variance = max_limit - min_limit

    current_value = min_limit + random.random() * total_variance

    print("current_value: {}".format(current_value))
    return current_value
```

Image for distribution with values:
average: 20
oscillation: 10
variance: 5

[image]